# Entity Framework 5.x 6.x Cache Frameworks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, redis, memcached

I am using EF5 in my current project and I will upgrade it to EF6. I know that EF has an internal query cache. This is all good, but I think it won't be enough for my needs. I want to use a cache server like memcache or redis. I know that Nhibernate have some very nice appenders like memcache. I find NCache with a quick internet search. But its documentation and samples seems outdated. So I'm not sure if I can use it. Are there any stable cache providers for EF5 or EF6?

Answer (score 2):

Try using EntityFramework.Extended cache with any cache mechanism you prefer.

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Query-Result-Cache

Answer (score 2):

There is no stable cache providers for EF6.1 yet but you can have a look here

[Second Level Cache for EF 6.1 | Code, the Universe and everything](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/03/20/second-level-cache-for-ef-6-1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this out of the box. EF6 doesn't support Second Level Caching.

You must implement a wrapper class for your db operations.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity{ public int Id { get;set; }

public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{

    T GetById(object id);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
}

public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private IDbSet<T> _entities;


    public EfRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(object id)
    {
        //Check cache first, if exists 
        return this.Entities.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {

        if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");


         this.Entities.Add(entity);
         //Add entity to cache
         this._context.SaveChanges();

    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        //Update cache
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            this._context.SaveChanges();

    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        //Remove from cache
        this.Entities.Remove(entity);
        this._context.SaveChanges();

    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Entities;
        }
    }

    protected virtual IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                _entities = _context.Set<T>();
            return _entities;
        }
    }
}
```

There are also oss implementations of caching provider on git hub [here](https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache) and a redis provider on top of it [here](https://github.com/silentbobbert/EFCache.Redis).

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft enterprise library caching block](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Caching/) is worth a look.

available over nuget `Install-Package EnterpriseLibrary.Caching`

[caching block Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28PandP.50%29.aspx)
and
[Caching Architecture Guide for .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817645.aspx)

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your solution. But, what I want is something implicit to use. I don't want to specifically use cache. I need some wrapper like this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx

Comment: Tracing and Caching for Entity Framework looks like an interesting tool. Sorry cant provide other examples.